# display public excerpt for private post

Tags: functions, excerpt, private

Thank you in advanced.
I know there are plugins that can do this, but I am looking for a simple solution for my function file. 
I would like to display the excerpt for all posts with the more tag for public visitors, even for private posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tested this, but you should be able to complete this task by placing the following code in your template above the loop.

```
query_posts(
    array(
        'post_status' => array(
            'published',
            'private'
        )
    )
);
```

This should allow for published and private posts to be displayed in that template.

Comment: Glad it worked! It's customary to mark an answer as accepted if it fixed the problem! Hope to see you around here some more.

Comment: Leads me to two more problems. Redirects to error if clicked on the <more>, and my loop with <endwhile: else> and <endif> had to be removed. Thank You again.

Comment: Write these as new questions and you might want to expand on the explanations.

Comment: @JimmyJack - your fix for an issue like this should definitely not involve removing the loop. Open up a new question regarding the redirect issue and post your code for the template so folks can take a look and give you some help.