# Private Post BUT Public excerpt on Homepage

Tags: excerpt, private

I'm building a website for [a french school](http://www.lfseoul.org/).

My problem : part of the website content will be private. Me and some other specified users will publish private posts (posts that only the 600 already-registred users will be abble to see).
But an excerpt of those posts (small photo+some text) shall be visible to any visitor in the Home page.
As soon as I set a post category to "Private" (using Role Scopper plugin), all excerpts of this post category, on the Home Page, also stop being displayed.

So what I'm trying to do is : "wheter or not a Post is set to private, force this excerpt to be displayed anyway". Note that I'm not a web dev, I just know a tiny bit of php.

Any plugin / hooks / code to put in the loop or somewhere else ?

Already tried [this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22593/display-public-excerpt-for-private-post), inserting the code in the index.php loop, but it didn't change anything.

I'm using a theme ([campus theme](http://themeforest.net/item/campus-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/5838533)) that had been largely re-arranged (css-wise).

*EDIT* 
Here is the template code of the homepage:

```
<!-- CONTENT -->
    <div class="content <?php echo $layout_class; ?>">
        <div class="content-inner">                     

        <!-- THE POST LOOP -->  
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
            <!-- Page Title -->
            <div class="page-title-breadcrumbs">
                <h1 class="page-title"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></h1>
                    <?php if(get_custom_field('show_breadcrumbs') == 'Yes') : ?>
                        <div class="breadcrumbs">| <?php echo get_breadcrumb(); ?></div><?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            <hr class="page-title-hr" />

            <!-- Page Caption Section -->
            <?php if(get_custom_field('page_caption') . get_custom_field('page_background_image')) : ?>

                <div class="<?php echo $layout_class; ?>" id="section-page-caption">
                    <?php get_template_part( 'includes/element', 'page-caption' ); ?>
                </div >

            <?php endif;?>  

            <!-- THE PAGE CONTENT -->
            <?php the_content(); ?>

            <!-- PAGINATION for Multiple pages -->
            <?php wp_link_pages('before=<br /><div id="page-links"><span>Pages:</span>&after=</div><hr />&link_before=<div>&link_after=</div>'); ?>             

            <!-- COMMENTS SECTION -->

            <?php comments_template(); ?> 
            <div class="hidden"><hr /><?php wp_list_comments('type="comment&avatar_size=64'); ?></div>
            <?php next_comments_link(); previous_comments_link(); ?>
            <div class="hidden"><?php comments_template( '', true ); ?></div>
            <!-- COMMENTS-SECTION -->


        <?php endwhile; ?>  

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /CONTENT -->
```

Thank you for your attention, gentlemen

and sorry if bad english ;)

Comment: The solution you linked to should work. I would say try another template other than index.php. Is there a front-page.php or home.php template in your theme?

Comment: I'm sure I found the right template, since when I put an echo before the loop it shows on the homepage. Though, I don't really know WHERE to put the code inside the php part. I edited my Post to add the code. Could you drive me on where I should put the code to solve my pb ?

Answer (score 1):

You could add this to your themes `functions.php` file. This adds `private` posts to the initial loop on the homepage only.

```
/**
 * Include private posts in homepage loop
 */
function show_private_posts_on_homepage($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish', 'private' ) );
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'show_private_posts_on_homepage');
```

Depending on your theme, you might need to swap out `$query->is_home()` with `$query->is_front_page()`

Comment: Actually, I might remove my answer - I hadn't read the explanation of Role Scoper, so this may not help.

Comment: I'm using Divi template and wanted private posts to show up in the blog module. 
Adding your solution to my functions.php did the trick.
I replaced if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) by if (!$query->is_single()) so that it would work everywhere where I use the blog module.
Thanks!