# Embedding Password Protected (Private) "Blog Posts" BLOCK that shows Images and Excerpts on Password Protected Page (not the home page)

Tags: pages, block-editor, blog, blog-page, privacy

My request is almost identical to that of the
[Private Post BUT Public excerpt on Homepage](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188715/private-post-but-public-excerpt-on-homepage) thread (similar use), with exception to this request being about a page that isn't set as the home page (regular page; not a post). I have the Premium WordPress account.

I have created a private password-protected page (not the homepage) with a URL of /aggregator then I created a private post and gave it a unique category.

When I go to embed the Blog Posts block and select the category, a message of "Sorry, no posts were found." is displayed while drafting, with nothing displayed when previewed (or published). Because private blog posts are excluded. (I have a plugin that allows me to exclude certain categories or tags from the homepage; so I'm covered there).

I'd like a password-protected private page with the password-protected private posts previewed (image with excerpts) on the password-protected private page, then once the title or "Read More" is clicked, a password prompt will be displayed to read the full content. I could not find a plugin that achieves this.

I am using a child theme for Morden. My permalinks for posts are set to /%author%/%postname%/

If you need more information, please let me know. Thank you so much for any and all help and or direction you can provide.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I have the Premium WordPress account"? If you're using WordPress.com hosting, you'll need to contact their support team.

Comment: I asked them for support on the issue, and they told me the scope of the question is something I should hire a developer for.